# Fast way to get the current voting rank?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I've a video model which has a votes_count. I already have a method which fetches the current rank.

```
def rank
  videos = Video.order('votes_count DESC')
  videos.index(self)+1
end
```

Is there a simpler solution which uses less cpu?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just count the number of videos with more than the current videos votes. This number plus one will be your rank.

```
def rank
  Video.where('votes_count > #{votes_count}').count + 1
end
```

Answer (score 1):

For optimize operation you can use de sql query operator MAX and the work is transfer to your Database Engine.

```
def rank
  ret =  Video.select('max(votes_count) as rank')
  ret.rank
end
```